# Оцените качество кода (Swift)

Tags: swift

Пишу на свифте около недели, вот начал разрабатывать очередное недоприложение.

Регистрация реализована на двух экранах:
- На первом нужно ввести логин, пароль, подтверждение пароля;
- На втором - имя и фамилию.

Приведенный ниже кусок кода просто проверяет наличие хотя бы одного символа в каждом из необходимых текстфилдов

Вопрос: насколько хорошо написан код с точки зрения расширения функционала и насколько корректен относительно стиля кодинга на свифт? Может что-то назвать покороче?

```
//
//  RegisterFormValidator.swift
//  RegisterApp
//
//  Created by Max Groshevsky on 27.03.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Max Groshevsky. All rights reserved.
//


// MARK: - Error codes
enum RegisterFormErrorCode {
    // First register page
    case usernameEmpty // Field Username is empty
    case passwordEmpty // Field Password is empty
    case confirmPasswordEmpty // Field Confirm password is empty
    case passwordsNotEqual // Fields Password and Confirm password not equal

    // Second register page
    case firstNameEmpty // Field First name is empty
    case lastNameEmpty // Field Last name is empty
}

// MARK: - Configure response to Presenter
struct RegisterFormErrorArray {
    var code: RegisterFormErrorCode
    var message: String

    init(errorCode: RegisterFormErrorCode, errorMessage: String) {
        self.code = errorCode
        self.message = errorMessage
    }
}

// MARK: - Register Form Verifyer
class RegisterFormValidator {

    // MARK: - First Register Page
    func pageFirst(username: String, password: String, confirmPassword: String) -> [RegisterFormErrorArray] {

        let getErrorCode = RegisterFormErrorCode.self
        var errors: [RegisterFormErrorArray] = []

        // ERROR: Field Username not filled
        if username.characters.count == 0 {
            let code = getErrorCode.usernameEmpty
            let message = "Field Username not filled"
            let error = RegisterFormErrorArray(errorCode: code, errorMessage: message)
            errors.append(error)
        }

        // ERROR: Field Password not filled
        if password.characters.count == 0 {
            let code = getErrorCode.passwordEmpty
            let message = "Field Password not filled"
            let error = RegisterFormErrorArray(errorCode: code, errorMessage: message)
            errors.append(error)
        }

        // ERROR: Field Confirm password not filled
        if confirmPassword.characters.count == 0 {
            let code = getErrorCode.confirmPasswordEmpty
            let message = "Field Confirm password not filled"
            let error = RegisterFormErrorArray(errorCode: code, errorMessage: message)
            errors.append(error)
        }

        // ERROR: Passwords not filled
        if password != confirmPassword {
            let code = getErrorCode.passwordEmpty
            let message = "Passwords not equal"
            let error = RegisterFormErrorArray(errorCode: code, errorMessage: message)
            errors.append(error)
        }

        return errors
    }

    // MARK: - Second Register Page
    func pageSecond(firstName: String, lastName: String) -> [RegisterFormErrorArray] {

        let getErrorCode = RegisterFormErrorCode.self
        var errors: [RegisterFormErrorArray] = []

        // ERROR: FirstName not filled
        if firstName.characters.count == 0 {
            let code = getErrorCode.firstNameEmpty
            let message = "Field First name not filled"
            let error = RegisterFormErrorArray(errorCode: code, errorMessage: message)
            errors.append(error)
        }

        // ERROR: LastName not filled
        if lastName.characters.count == 0 {
            let code = getErrorCode.firstNameEmpty
            let message = "Field Last name not filled"
            let error = RegisterFormErrorArray(errorCode: code, errorMessage: message)
            errors.append(error)
        }

        return errors
    }
}
```

Заранее благодарю

Comment: С точки зрения расширения плохо! А с точки зрения новичка, сойдет =) Например: за место тучи повторных переменных и ненужных действий, как вы написали в `pageFirst` - это можно было написать `1` раз отдельной функцией, а в `pageFirst` использовать только вхождение в написанную функцию, этим повысится читабельность и удобство использования, либо вообще юзать цикл, что будет самым подходящим для вашего случая .

Answer (score 0):

Первое, ошибки:

```
enum RegisterFormErrorCode {
// First register page
    case usernameEmpty ...
```

Посмотрите в документации [Errors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error)

Используйте стандартный механизм

```
enum RegisterFormError: Error {
    case usernameEmpty ...
и описание к ним
extension RegisterFormError: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? { ...
```

Так Вам не нужно инициализировать code, message, error и со стандартными ошибками работать удобнее.

---

Данная проверка:

```
if username.characters.count == 0 {
```

плоха сложностью O(n). Мелочь, но из мелочей строится грандиозное. Используйте [isEmpty O(1)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2946268-isempty)

```
userName.isEmpty
```

Ну и воспринимается легче.

---

Ну и второй метод будет, условно, таким, коли его суть возвращать ошибки:

```
func pageSecond(firstName: String, lastName: String) -> [RegisterFormError] {
    var errors: [RegisterFormError] = []
    if firstName.isEmpty {
        errors.append(.firstNameEmpty)
    }
    if lastName.isEmpty {
        errors.append(.lastNameEmpty)
    }
    return errors
}
```

---

Это первое за что зацепился глаз по Вашему коду.

Насчет именования - это наверное один из крупнейших камней преткновения. Придерживайтесь Swift code style, хорошо расписано у [raywenderlich](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide), ну и конечно же [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/). Но многое может перекрываться соглашениями/требованиями в команде.

Answer (score 0):

**Просто заметил...**
В этом блоке:

```
// ERROR: LastName not filled
    if lastName.characters.count == 0 {
        let code = getErrorCode.firstNameEmpty
        let message = "Field Last name not filled"
        let error = RegisterFormErrorArray(errorCode: code, errorMessage: message)
        errors.append(error)
    }
```

**константа let code должна быть инициализирована getErrorCode.lastNameEmpty**

**Можно создание ошибки в виде code и message вынести в отдельную функцию, чтобы исключить дублирование кода и ошибки копи-паста)))...**

```
func errorConstructer(code: RegisterFormErrorCode) -> RegisterFormErrorArray {
var error = RegisterFormErrorArray(errorCode: code, errorMessage: "")
switch code {
case .confirmPasswordEmpty:
    error.message = "Field Confirm password not filled"
    return error
case .firstNameEmpty:
    error.message = "Field First name not filled"
    return error
case .lastNameEmpty:
    error.message = "Field Last name not filled"
    return error
case .passwordEmpty:
    error.message = "Field Password not filled"
    return error
case .passwordsNotEqual:
    error.message = "Passwords not equal"
    return error
case .usernameEmpty:
    error.message = "Field Username not filled"
    return error
}
```

}

Таким образом предыдущие блоки кода будут иметь вид...

```
// ERROR: Field Username not filled
    if username.characters.count == 0 {
        let error = errorConstructer(code: getErrorCode.usernameEmpty)
        errors.append(error)
    }
```